# get name of files in a folder with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

1. I have a background image folder that there is some picture that i want to use them for background.
2. how i can get their names and put them on array whit javascript?if i cant they do with **javascript**,how can i do that?
3. i want to read name of files and use javacsript and link for change background image whit css.

   ```
   <script>
    function  nextbg(){
   $('#bg').css('background-image','url(Images/bg2.jpg)'); 
    }
    </script>
   ```

Comment: You generally don't have access to any folders from the browser

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want the functionality to work for these backgrounds?

Comment: it sounds like the question is about getting a list of files from the _server_.  which is less impossible.

Comment: However, there's no way we could do it! Even with other language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution is created according to the fact that browser dont have access to folders/filesystem.

Javascript can **not** access the filesystem. This has to be done by a **server script** and then be feed to the javascript.

I had the simliar problem when building my game engine when I was loading all my diffrent tiles. I ended up doing it like this.

**This solution do pose two a problems when implementing it.**

1. You will have to define the amout of images in the "NrofTiles" array
2. The images must be named like tile1, tile2 ... tile9 so you can
   increment the path to them.

The **typeOfTiles[typeCounter]** is just there to give me access to different folders, in my case for my tiles, grass, houses, water and so on.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= nrofTiles.length; i++)    
{
    for(var x = 0; x <= nrofTiles[i]; x++)
    {       
        console.log
        ("Fetching tile "+(x + 1 )+" of " + 14);
        img = new Image();
        //My path
        img.src = 'Images/Cart/' + typeOfTiles[typeCounter] + '/' + (x + 1) + '.png';
        imgArray.push(img);

            var intervalFunctionen = function () {      

                alert("calls back here");
            };

    }//end for loop!
 }end outer for loop!
```

When everything is loaded(the tiles), you do this to change the background picture.

**This is an example of a changing body background**. You could make a link with an ID lets say "iamthelink".

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="iamthelink">Change BG</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var link = document.getElementsById('iamthelink');

link.onclick= function() {
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://localhost/background.png)';
}
```